# how to avoid server-side set-cookie when curl post data?

Tags: php, curl

We have a intranet website , we use it query information by user ID, and here is a sample of the website cookie.

```
  # Netscape HTTP Cookie File                                                                            
  # http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html                                                             
  # This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.                                           

  192.168.202.200   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  SX2NVyVkj4YlY2Zv7857Mdyy5RpdfQWmLjYjqtnWTF4x9nRghxcr!1083570229
```

I use web developer copy cookie(and some  web element) from firefox to chrome.  chrome can work  correctly.
but when i use  php code like this:

```
<?php
$cookie = tempnam('.','cookie'); 

$url='http://192.168.202.200/bbs/query.jsp';

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
$output = curl_exec($ch) ;
$fh = fopen("cookie.html", 'w') ;
fwrite($fh, $output) ;
fclose($fh) ;
curl_close($ch); 
preg_match("/<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"myname\" value=\"(.*)\"\/>/isU",$output,$myname);    

$url='http://192.168.202.200/bbs/SomeAction.do';
$curlPost='billNum=1049090347503&myname='.$myname[1];
$ch = curl_init($url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);   
$output = curl_exec($ch) ;
$fh = fopen("out.html", 'w') ;
fwrite($fh, $output) ;
fclose($fh) ; 
curl_close($ch); 

@unlink($cookie);
?>
```

my php code cannot do a success query, but only got a a webpage indicating “query checking mechanism error” which seems generate by web automatic-prevent-querying .

`'http://192.168.202.200/bbs/query.jsp'` is a iframe of the homepage, and `'http://192.168.202.200/bbs/SomeAction.do'` has a iframe which does the query.

i change CURLOPT_HEADER to 1,then get header like this：
`HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie" Date: Fri, 11 Oct 2013 15:10:21 GMT Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html; charset=GB2312 Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=SYJd5J2b2C7FN2LPXVQfHk3vp4mmpTlKBtBbLbCT1HGfmX2kXGtR!-860145551; path=/ X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.4 JSP/2.0`
apparently the problem is here . `Cache-Control:no-cache="set-cookie"`, how to avoid Reponse header to `set-cookie`.

thanks.

Comment: Make sure that the different usage of `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` is not the problem.

Comment: i got the sample cookie by php code above. so  the usage of  `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` is no the problem, i think.